# How do I express a function that returns a setof record in sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I need to execute a pg function that returns a setof record type.
Here is the function in postgres:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION testfunction(text, text)
RETURNS SETOF RECORD AS
   'select * from test;'
LANGUAGE sql;
```

Here is the python:

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy.sql import *

engine = sa.create_engine('postgresql://localhost/test')
conn = engine.connect()
f = func.testfunction('a', 'b')
conn.execute(select([column('a', sa.types.Integer)]).select_from(f))
```

What I need is to say:

```
SELECT a FROM testfunction('a', 'b') AS (a integer)
```

...but I don't know how to express that.

Comment: Aside: Don't quote the language name: `LANGUAGE sql`.

Comment: I see... quotes are for backward compatibility.  Didn't take long to figure out, but let me know next time why I should/shouldn't do something.  Thanks.

Comment: Strictly speaking, quotes are *incorrect*. The language name is an identifier, not a string. It's only tolerated because old (bad) habbits die hard. It has been like that .. almost forever. There is no more "backward compatibility" left. Proper syntax may be required for a future release. So, you'd better stay *forward compatible*. I have been fixing this so many times, I am getting tired of it, thus the short notice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears you can't:

From http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/functions.html#sqlalchemy.sql.functions.func

> The func construct has only limited support for calling standalone “stored procedures”, especially those with special parameterization concerns.
>
> See the section [Calling Stored Procedures](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/connections.html#stored-procedures) for details on how to use the DBAPI-level callproc() method for fully traditional stored procedures.

Obviously, you can fall back to plain SQL interpolation:

```
>> print sa.select().select_from('a AS f(a int, b int)')
SELECT  
FROM a AS f(a int, b int)
```

Comment: Can you explain why I can't?  Is there no way to express the `AS (type1, type2, ...)` clause?  I also didn't see much of an answer in that storedproc function.  How did that help?  Can you show an example?

Comment: Indeed, there appears to be no way of creating an `AS (type list)` clause.