# How do I use PostgreSQL's jsonb_to_record in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, jsonb

PostgreSQL has functions like `jsonb_to_record` or `jsonb_populate_record` which allow you convert data stored in a JSONB column to separate columns. however, I'm using SQLAlchemy and `jsonb_to_record` requires a predefined structure for the output (see example below from the PostgreSQL docs)

```
select * from json_to_record('{"a":1,"b":[1,2,3],"c":"bar"}') as x(a int, b text, d text)
```

Is there a way to use these functions from SQLAlchemy?

Comment: By SQLAlchemy, are we talking about the [ORM](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/index.html) or the [core](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/index.html) part?

Comment: both, if possible, please.

Comment: I think this answer should help https://stackoverflow.com/a/25046952/4454340

Answer (score 2):

you can use any postgres function in SQLAlchemy with func like so:

```py
from SQLAlchemy import func
session.query(func.json_to_record(Model.jsonb_field))
```

Do note that set-returning functions are a bit of a pain to deal with with SQLAlchemy, but if you want you can get it to work.